# How to make JavaScript countdown timer work again and again on clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On clicking a button with **id next-problem** , an **AJAX** request is send to server and new task get loaded. I want to restart the timer when new task get loaded. In AJAX , on success I want to reset timer. But the problem is many **setInterval** get starts on click the button. How to avoid that ?

```
    var timer;
var countdownfunction;
var countDownTime;

timer = function (){

    clearInterval(countdownfunction);

    countDownTime = $("#timer").attr("data-timer-val");

    var countdownfunction = setInterval(function() {

        if(countDownTime < 10 ){
            var temp = "0" + countDownTime;
            $("#time").text(temp);
        }else{
            $("#time").text(countDownTime);
        }


        countDownTime = countDownTime - 1;



        if (countDownTime < 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownfunction);
            $("#time-expired").text("Please click next problem.");
        }

    }, 1000);
} ;


$(document).ready(function(){
    timer();
});


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#next-problem").on('click', function(){

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',

            url : '/test/next-problem/',

            success : function(data){
                // console.log(data);
                $("#problem-content").html(data);
                clearInterval(countdownfunction);
                timer();

            },

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Where is your ajax request? I don't see it in the code

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't think so ajax code is required. FYI ajax code is written in another file.

Comment: You say you want to resume the timer when the new task loads, so figuring out *when that occurs* and how to trigger an event at the end is pivotal to knowing how the timeout can be resumed at the desired time.

Comment: You need to set 'countDownTime' to a fresh value after you have received the new task.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  Ajax code is added

Comment: @PoulBak countDownTime is getting fresh value each time . The problem is many setInterval works simultaneously.

Comment: if you are getting multiple setInterval calls then you have setup multiple click handlers which in turn calls your timer function multiple times. Is the url you are requesting in your ajax request the same page that is including your javascript code? Meaning is the page you are loading including more of the same javascript code

Comment: You don't show the code, that updates 'countDownTime'. Please show that.

Comment: @PatrickEvans please see the updated code.

Comment: @CertainPerformance please see the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `var` from the following line:

```
var countdownfunction = setInterval(function() {
```

Because of this `var` you have two differently scoped values of `countdownfunction` so when you call `clearInterval` you are never clearing this particular functionally-scoped value until that timer reaches `-1`, so you may have multiple timers running on top of each other.

Once you remove `var` here, you now have a single, globally-scoped variable that can be cleared and reassigned a value.

Comment: Thanks bud. I have found it, that was so silly that I didn't notice it.